# Syntax error when using BEGIN .. END in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

With my stored procedure, this works fine

```
INSERT INTO gearLog (code, signeeID, signoutDate, signbackDate, committeeOutID, committeeInID, warningsGiven)
    VALUES (@codeI, @signeeIDI, @signoutDateI, NULL, @committeeI, NULL, 0)
```

But this causes an error

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO gearLog (code, signeeID, signoutDate, signbackDate, committeeOutID, committeeInID, warningsGiven)
    VALUES (@codeI, @signeeIDI, @signoutDateI, NULL, @committeeI, NULL, 0)
END
```

Why? I want to use this snippet in a bigger piece of code but it won't compile. Thanks

Comment: Are you writing the procedure on mysql cli or some other tool ?

Comment: I am writing it through phpMyAdmin, their 'add routine' window.

Comment: What kind of error is caused by your example code?

Comment: You will need to set the delimiter properly ! when you do begin-end your syntax should look like `begin .... end;//` here `//` is the procedure delimiter, and also need to make sure each command inside `begin end` should be having `;` as the closing statement.

Comment: 1064:

MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
INSERT INTO gearLog (code, signeeID, signoutDate, signbackDate, committee' at line 8

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried specifiying the delimiter and adding the semicolons as you have said, but I still get the syntax error. If you promote your comment to an answer, I can comment on it further

Answer (score 0):

As I made this procedure through the 'add routine' window of phpMyAdmin, I did not need to specify a delimiter. I was just missing the semicolon after the VALUES statement

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO gearLog (code, signeeID, signoutDate, signbackDate, committeeOutID, committeeInID, warningsGiven)
    VALUES (@codeI, @signeeIDI, @signoutDateI, NULL, @committeeI, NULL, 0);
END
```